# JS synchronous not firing in order

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript function which is not firing in order. It fires the `CheckForAddRecordsToAddFromDSS` method, then the `if (check1 || check2)` statement before even firing the `CheckForMissingRecordsFromSupp` method.

Why is this happening?

```
$.getJSON("/Home/CheckForMissingRecordsFromSupp", function (data) {
        check1 = data;
    }).done($.getJSON("/Home/CheckForAddRecordsToAddFromDSS", function (data) {
        check2 = data;
    }).done(function () {
    if (check1 || check2) {
                location.reload();
            }
    })
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

`.done` expects to be passed a function. You are passing the return value of `$.getJSON` which is not a function.

Consider the following example:

```
foo(bar())
```

Even without knowing anything about `foo` or `bar`, we definitely know that `bar` is executed **before** `foo` and `bar`'s return value is passed to `foo`.

Your code should be:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/CheckForMissingRecordsFromSupp", function(data) {
  check1 = data;
}).done(function() { // <- function
  $.getJSON("/Home/CheckForAddRecordsToAddFromDSS", function(data) {
    check2 = data;
  }).done(function() {
    if (check1 || check2) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Having said that, since `.done` also receives the network response, you don't need to pass a callback to `$.getJSON`. You can just write:

```
$.getJSON("/Home/CheckForMissingRecordsFromSupp").done(function(check1) {
  $.getJSON("/Home/CheckForAddRecordsToAddFromDSS").done(function(check2) {
    if (check1 || check2) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```